# How to get this attribute value from custom product attribute in picture?

Tags: product

How to get this attribute value from custom product attribute in picture with product id?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
<?php
// pseudo code

// Put the product's id you are looking for here.
$productId = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getAttributeText('process_id');
```

If you are doing this through a collection, DO NOT RUN THE ABOVE CODE INSIDE A LOOP!!
Instead, do this:

```
<?php
// pseudo code
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('process_id');

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getAttributeText('process_id');
}
```

Comment: this is not work i need to get "empty" value please check picture !

Comment: Does the product in question have that value selected?

Comment: I just updated the answer try the new solution.